# Multiple delete in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I try to create a stored procedure with this code but I can't create it.
I can create a stored procedure with only one of each delete and it works.

DELETE FROM mostra WHERE fine

DELETE FROM spettacolo WHERE id IN (
SELECT id_spettacolo
FROM spettacolo_teatro
WHERE data < CURDATE( );

Comment: put a semi-colon after the first delete...also, doesn't seem like the first delete's WHERE clause is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your DELETE -statements, but after that you should be able to do the following:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE your_delete_proc () 
begin
DELETE FROM mostra WHERE fine; 
DELETE FROM spettacolo WHERE id IN ( SELECT id_spettacolo FROM spettacolo_teatro WHERE data < CURDATE( ));
END //
delimiter ;
```